# ng-show not working on angularjs the div is still hidden

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm assigning the response data to the $scope but the div with the ng-show  remains hidden. I'm noob on angularjs,what is wrong??

```
else {
         debugger;
         $scope.exception = data.exception; //data arrives correctly
```

and the html

```
<div class="error-text"  ng-show="exception.code">
```

but that it's not working and there is no error shown on the console

Comment: "ng-show" expects boolean value, so what's the value of exception.code?

Comment: it's a string  doen't it evaluate if its null or not?

Comment: Could you share more of the js controller code?

Comment: @afccc , that's correct, `null` will evaluate to false. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Piyush Your statement is not true. The `ng-show` directive operates on [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. See [AngularJS ng-show Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Comment: @georgeawg yes I said boolean value (true or false), isn't it?

Comment: @Piyush All values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) unless they are defined as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Examples of truthy values in JavaScript: `3.14`, `"false"`, `{}`, `"string"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-show` directive operates on [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

If the `exception` lacks a code property, the element will not show itself.

Try:

```
 ̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶=̶"̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶-̶t̶e̶x̶t̶"̶ ̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶h̶o̶w̶=̶"̶e̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶c̶o̶d̶e̶"̶>̶
 <div class="error-text"  ng-show="exception">
     exception = {{exception}}
 </div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-show Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: The problem is that  exception has the property code but the html is not shown

Answer (score -1):

'ng-show' works on a boolean value, so you simply need to set ***$scope.exception.code = true;***, make sure your object inside exception has a boolean key by name 'code'.

So your JS code will be like this:

```
else {
         debugger;
         $scope.exception = data.exception;//data arrives correcly
         $scope.exception.data = true;
}
```

Comment: Your statement is not true. The `ng-show` directive operates on [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. See [AngularJS ng-show Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).